# Change a session value based on another session value in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am trying to update a session value based on another session value change. Basically in `$_SESSION['amount']` I am updating a price value from a dropdown change.

What I am trying based on this dropdown value l will update another session `$_SESSION['adtitle']` I have written following code. It works first time but after that `$_SESSION['adtitle']` value doesn't change though `$_SESSION['amount']` value changes rather shows first time updated value always.

The following is my code:

```
<?php

  session_start();
  if ($_SESSION['amount']==10) {
     $_SESSION['adtitle'] = "1 week sticky";}

  else if($_SESSION['amount']==15){
    $_SESSION['adtitle'] = "2 week sticky";}

 else {
    $_SESSION['adtitle'] = "3 week sticky";}


?>
```

Comment: You didn't include how you change `$_SESSION['amount']`. My guess is that when you change it, the page does not reload, and because of that, your code will not run again.

Comment: `$_SESSION['amount']` is updating after submit button press and then  i am redirecting the page into a 2nd page.In the 2nd page i am trying to update the `$_SESSION['adtitle']` value  based on `$_SESSION['amount']` value

Comment: Your code is in the 2nd page?

Comment: yes this code is in the 2nd page and `$_SESSION['amount']` is updating from the 1st page on submit button click

Comment: Hi Mithu. Please don't throw away good edits. I have restored my change, as it is beyond debate that it is an improvement. If you wish to insist on your version, would you let me know, so we can ask a moderator to take a view on it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `$_SESSION['amount']` value is not updating correctly on time above code run so firstly you can check the value of `$_SESSION['amount'].`

Hope this will help